# stripe subscription from first date of the month with initial fee

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to do stripe monthly subscription with these conditions

- monthly charge 30 dollars
- payment should be done first date of the month
- when registration is done in the middle of the month daily rate fee should be paid at the timing registration is done

for example, user registered August 10th

- 20 dollars should be paid at that timing
- 30 us dollar subscription is done at September 1st and following first date of the month

how can I configure this?
I want to know the configuration for stripe.checkout.sessions

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would achieve exactly what you seek by setting the billing cycle anchor on the 1st of the next month and allow a prorated invoice to be generated for the partial period until then:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions

However, this option for the Subscription create API is not available via Checkout:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data

You could achieve a similar result by setting `subcription_data[trial_end]` to be the 1st of the next month to effectively set the billing anchor then:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#using-a-trial-to-change-the-billing-cycle
You'll need to calculate your own prorated amount for the first month, and then add a one-time Price in the `line_items` alongside the recurring Price to add the prorated amount to the first invoice only:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items

Comment: Both trial_end and billing_cycle_anchor cannot be set to each line_item but it is can be set to subscription data.
It means if I set either setting, both subscription and initial payment is delayed. 

I want to get initial payment when user registered. Is it possible?